# How to get network info in angular

Tags: angular, wifi

Hi I am trying to get the network info in my angular application.
Like whether n/w conn available and what  wifi it is connected to.
I am able to monitor n/w using ng-connection-service , is there any way I can get info like what wifi it is connected to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigator.connection` in your code. But the information are limited.

You can find [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API).

Comment: Property 'connection' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Comment: Just try in your navigator. If it doesn't exist, just do `(navigator as any).connection`